# Finding the measurement of an angle.

Tags: trigonometry

My question is the following:Is there any way we can calculate ( by hand ) the inverse trigonometric function of a trigonometric function so that we get the measurement of the angle to which the functions correspond to? 
In other ways : Let x be the measure of the angle
       x=arcsine(sine x)
Is there any algorithm for finding x ? I have been searching the internet for an answer , but it seems that everyone is using a calculator...

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: A google search for "algorithm for arcsin" gets lots of hits: here is quite a good one: http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/algorithms.htm

Answer (score 1):

We have $ \sin ( 
\sin^{-1} x ) = x, \forall x \in [-1,1]$ and $\sin^{-1}(\sin x ) = x$ is true only for $x \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$